# Why would a country restrict foreign airlines from flying to their airports?

Tags: trade

It is often mentioned in the media how country X signed an agreement with country Z, allowing the establishment of a certain air route between the two countries. Large countries may also be keen on signing [open skies agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU%E2%80%93US_Open_Skies_Agreement) between each other, allowing unrestricted flights between any points of each other's territory.

However it seems strange to me that countries would need to restrict the [freedoms of the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedoms_of_the_air) in the first place. Why not simply allow any airline in the world to fly to your airports, as long as they fulfill the safety aspects and can pay the relevant fees? Wouldn't this serve to boost the number of people visiting your country? I am aware that many states have a [flag carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_carrier), but their profits are often so minuscule, it wouldn't really matter for the state budget if they face increased competition.

Comment: Their profits are minuscule. That doesn't mean that if their profits go down it has no impact on budget. Are their costs minuscule as well? If I am making a dollar profit now, and losing a billion next year, that will weigh on budget.

Comment: @oerkelens in any case the goal of air travel (from the state's perspective) is to increase the number of visitors, rather than profit for the flag carrier. That is unless you count microstates such as Singapore.

Comment: `the goal of air travel (from the state's perspective) is to increase the number of visitors, rather than profit for the flag carrier`**Citation needed**. In any case a) it is not only profit, local companies will hire local, pay local taxes, can be incentivated to buy locally produced planes b) Newcomers will most likely try to serve the most profitable routes, which may lead to disproportionate losers to stablished companies and c) the historical "default" already forbid that for shipping (see **cabotaje**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The genesis of such restrictions date back to the Golden Age of air travel.

In the 1930's, air travel was just becoming economically viable, and safe enough to be practical. Initially, the benefit wasn't so much human travel, it was rapid delivery of mail, which expanded commerce between countries considerably - mail being the 'internet' of that time, critical to a country's commerce, and air mail vs ground mail being roughly equivalent to dial up on a 1200bps line to megabit broadband - the speed increase made commerce far more economical and flexible.

This huge boost to commerce was most applicable to [trans Atlantic travel](http://www.century-of-flight.net/new%20site/commercial/Transatlantic%20Services.htm), already booming with the large passenger ships. Thus, those early airlines such as Pan American, Imperial, KLM, and Lufthansa, had become unofficial 'instruments of state policy', an extension to the diplomatic corp of the host nation by virtue of their rapid travel.

Consequently, to prevent the US from getting a commercial, diplomatic and prestige advantage, the British insisted on a [reciprocity agreement](http://www.clipperflyingboats.com/transatlantic-airline-service)... the US could not get landing rights in the UK for transatlantic air travel, until the UK could provide a similar service. As the UK was the nearest European country to the US, it was the prime landing spot.

This led to a delay in transatlantic air service between the two countries until the UK could develop an aircraft capable of making the journey - a primary reason that Pan Am established the much longer trans Pacific routes before the trans Atlantic routes. The first passenger flights between the US and Britain began in 1939, with routes to the UK and to Lisbon in Portugal. During the war, the Lisbon route became a prime means of moving diplomats and spies between the two warring factions.

As airliners increased in range and dropped in cost (due in no small part to the rapid bomber tech advances of WW2), the number of airlines increased, and the 'instrument of state policy' status faded away as rapid mail delivery became the standard.

Today, air travel between nations is critical, but not as important as it was in the 1930's. Any such limitations today are related more to foreign policy (sanctions), security concerns (a foreign nation not securing its airports), safety concerns (poorly maintained aircraft), or overcrowding concerns at major airports like JFK or Heathrow. There are only so many high profit terminals available at those airports, and all of them are already occupied.

And, to a degree, the habit of reciprocity insisted on by the UK in the late 1930's is probably still a factor, that appeals to the national pride of the less economically successful nations.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, a government might want to favour one airport from another.

Taking as example my closest airport, a small sized, one terminal, one land strip  LEDA ( Lleida - Alguaire ), the national airport authorities (AENA), decided to disallow flights from and to Russia and to other local airports, limiting it's operability to the Balear islands, Israel and UK.

The reason is technical and economical, allowing more flights from Russia would lower the flights on other, less close to their destination airports like LEBL (Barcelona - El Prat), and mathematically making it less profitable.

The example was small scaled, but on a global perspective, you can understand that limiting operability allows both countries to better manage tourist and economical impact on regions. Airports that would end loosing flights, like the Madrid-Barajas airport, if the flights were non regulated, the flights that it currently holds, part  of whom are  international connections to the high speed train system or local flight routes, would suffer a lot from more interesting, cheap and "en-route" airports like Gran Canaria or Barcelona.

Comment: The airports themselves are free to accept or reject new flight destinations, once the government hurdles are passed. My question is about why the government restricts flights, not why individual airports might want to.

Comment: What i said is about government, not airports.  Paragraph 2. That downvote hurt D: